# PHP select n number of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm facing this problem that I can't seem to figure a way out of. I have an array like this,

```
    $array = [(
    "name" => "marks", "score" => 24),
    ("name" => "arsh", "score"=>54),
    ("name" => "jack" , "score" =>32),
    ("name" => "welch" , "score" =>34),
    ("name" => "sid" , "score" =>32)];
```

How can I select the first n number of arrays like lets say I need to first 2 arrays. So out of this data how can I get an output like this,

```
    $array = [(
    "name" => "marks", "score" => 24),
    ("name" => "arsh", "score"=>54)]
```

Thanks

Comment: [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) should help

Comment: [`array_slice($array, 0, 2)`](http://www.php.net/array_slice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/array_slice) should do the trick:

```
$firstTwo = array_slice ($array, 0, 2);
```